# Android - Single button in Activity used in over 3 Fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments

So I'm using `AppbarLayout` which gives every `Fragment` replaced onto the `FrameLayout` (my container) scrolled a bit downwards.. I don't know what it's called but that's a normal `AppbarLayout` behavior, yes?

So I need a footer which will stay in the bottom of screen, containing a button for specifically 3 `Fragments` and it's not possible (I might be wrong here) if I put each and every footer for each `Fragment` because the footer will be pushed downwards at first until user scrolls up.

I did `((MainActivity)getActivity).btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(...))` in all those `Fragment` with different method inside the listener. Weirdly, or maybe this is the right behavior, when I click on the `Fragment` A's referenced `Button`, the second it calls the method and move to the next `Fragment`, the method in `Fragment` B is somehow called and I am unable to press the `Button` referenced in `Fragment` B anymore. Tried adding the method of `Button` referenced in B to onCreate, but it still doesn't work.

Anybody know what is the reason of this?? Or am I actually doing a bad approach on using footer for `Fragment` inside `AppbarLayout`?

Comment: Hello, did you try what I suggest?

Comment: Ah sorry I forgot to answer it, was too busy working on another part of the code lol.. No I didn't.. Because it is what I've already did lol, what I wanted is how to get the reference on the button, not the layout arrangement.. Hmm is my wording wrong? It seems you got the wrong idea..

Comment: Pls. see my updated answer. Or you need to have a Button in each Fragment? And I think that setting OnClickListener from Fragment is not so good idea.

Comment: Okay I'm checking it now while in a meeting lol.. No, only in 3 specific Fragments.. Yes I agree.. But, sadly, I don't know other method..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, my approach let's you to have a button in your `Activity` and on pressing that button manage behaviour of your `Fragments`.
Instead of `FrameLayout` you can easily use something like that:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="Press me"/>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#c3c3c3"
        android:layout_above="@+id/button" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Here is your `Button` and your container for `Fragments`.
Then attach `OnClickListener` on that Button and in `onClick()` replace `Fragments` inside a container or manage your current Fragment by `findFragment` or `getFragments` method (you will find your current Fragment and run appropriate method).

**One more try :)**
If you need to have a button in each `Fragment` - set single `OnClickListener` in your `Activity`.
Then, in each `Fragment` set `btn.setOnClickListener((YourActivity)getActivity())`.
In `Activity's` `onClick()` again you can do whatever you want with `Fragments`.

Comment: Oh so in Activity, I take the currently active Fragment and make `switch` or `if` condition depending on which Fragment is active?

Comment: If your button is in Activity - yes. If your button is in Fragments - you can call ((YourActivity) getActivity()).yourSwitchMethod().

Comment: Ahh, let me try that! Will try after this meeting lol, that's a good approach which eludes my logic, damn why I made everything so hacky

Comment: Try and let me know the result )

Comment: Dude, did you try?

Comment: I tried using 2 methods, one is the one you said, the other one is creating several btns and set on click listener on each one, the second method is kinda annoying lol, I think the method you gave is better! Would it create a hard reference on the btn inside the fragment tho? Can it be GCed normally?

Comment: Sorry, didn't got you now. You created one Button in MainActivity or button in each Fragment?

Comment: The second method was, 4 btns in MainActivity with 4 different listeners, and depending on the Fragment, 1 will be shown, the rest will be gone lol, inefficient.... So, soon after doing some stuffs on OOM issue in the app, I'll get back to the btns.. A quick question, the listener will have its view casted to btn, right? And a `switch case` or `if else` would be made for the `ID` of the view right?

Comment: If you provide different Buttons, in onClick(View v) you can just use switch(v.getId()), no need to make cast.

Comment: Ohh I see, so either can be done, just different approach! Thanks for the information :D

Answer (score 0):

Try this replace fragments in FrameLayout with id content_frame.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/footer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <View
        android:id="@+id/foter_border"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="2dp"
        android:background="#03A14D" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/footer_place_holder"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:background="#70000000"
            android:ellipsize="marquee"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
            android:freezesText="true"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:scrollHorizontally="true"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:text="Footer without any action"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:visibility="visible" >
        </Button>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/content_frame"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_above="@+id/order_root"
    android:background="@color/background_light_gray"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="Main Content" >
</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: Sorry, have to use `AppbarLayout` so the `FrameLayout` has to be inside `CoordinatorLayout` which contains the `AppbarLayout`

Comment: You can make view hierarchy like this make RelativeLayout as parent , put footer layout on bottom of relative layout.  Then put coordinate layout above your footer. Your coordinate will contain appbar and frame layout for fragment transition.

Comment: I did that, but the problem is.. When I click on the button, the onClickListener executed twice.. Should I reinitialize with new for each btn for every method or just add 3 btn from the start?